# Creating Node.JS HTTPS server in Cloud9 IDE

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, server, cloud9

Is it somehow possible to create a Node.js https server in cloud9 IDE?

Below is my example of simple https server setup in Node.js.

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = require('./app');

// SSL Configuration
var ca_names = ['CERT-NAME_1', 'CERT-NAME_2', 'CERT-NAME_3'];
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./folder/server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./folder/server.crt'),
  ca: ca_names.map(function(n) {
    return fs.readFileSync('./eid/ca/' + n + '.crt');
  }),
  //crl: ca_names.map(function(n) { return fs.readFileSync('/eid/ca/' + n + '.crl'); }),
  requestCert: false,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};

var server = https.createServer(options, app);
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8081, process.env.IP || "0.0.0.0");
console.log('server listening on port: ' + process.env.PORT);
```

when I try to connect to the server then I am getting following error:

> "ECONNRESET: Request could not be proxied!"

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are trying to listen to both HTTP and HTTPS. 
c9 works as a proxy so you only need to listen on HTTP even though you are trying to use HTTPS. Try not listening to HTTPS and it should work. ([more info on this](https://community.c9.io/t/unable-to-do-https-on-c9users-io-request-could-not-be-proxied/11975/5))
But, if you really need HTTPS, in that case you can use a proxy like Nginx to internally proxy requests over HTTPS.(more info on this)[enter link description here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/)